# Get values of nested JSON file in python 3.4 using loop

Tags: json, python-3.x, nested

```
import json
data = []    
with open('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\file.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:      #open file
    data = json.load(json_data)     # load into list
for x in data:                   #now iterate by all values(2 cycles)

 for eachindex in x["fields"]:           #this part WORKS
        print(str(x["fields"][eachindex]["items"]))

        for eachindex2 in x["fields"][eachindex]["items"]:  # this part doesn`t work
            print(eachindex2["fields"][eachindex]["items"]["description"])
```

How to make cycle for getting inner values of nested JSON file?
GET ERROR:KeyError: 'fields' 
HOW TO GET DESCRIPTIONS OF ALL fields? And MARK of cars if they exists? Could not get such values(

```
     MY FILE:   [
      {
    "fields": {
      "1.0": {
        "units": "грн",
        "title": "авторська винагорода, інші доходи від реалізації майнових прав інтелектуальної власності",
        "items": []
      },
      "35.0": {
        "units": "",
        "title": "Автомобіль легковий",
        "items": [
          {
            "description": "3.5",    #NOT all fields have such value
            "model": "Cayenne",      #NOT all fields have such value
            "source": "сайт ВРУ",    #NOT all fields have such value
            "year": "2011",          #NOT all fields have such value
            "mark": "Porsche",       #NOT all fields have such value
            "id": 159067             #NOT all fields have such value
          }
        ]
      }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID IT! just using try catch to check if value exists
 for x in data:
    for eachindex in x["fields"]:
        try:

```
        print(str(x["fields"][eachindex]["items"][0]))    #WORKING
    except IndexError:
        pass
```